# 360 Video with navigation menu

Tags: html, video, jwplayer, 360-virtual-reality, bitmovin-player

I'm looking to build a microsite that has a fullscreen 360 video. I've been doing some research but can't seem to find the answer. Is it possible to have a full screen 360 video using JWPlayer, Bitmovin or another HTML5 player with static navigation elements on top if it? I think it would be feasible by changing the z index of the top element but haven't been able to verify this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bitmovin Player](https://bitmovin.com/html5-player/) does support this use case either through the Player API (your own controls that control the player through JavaScript) or by modifying the [player Skin](https://github.com/bitmovin/bitmovin-player-ui) (available in Bitmovin-Player v7).

So let's say you want to overlay a Play button over the video you would just define a  element that then calls `.play()` on the player instance.

```
$('.play-button').click(function () {
  player.play();
});
```

The button can then easily be skinned and placed above the player with CSS.

Although changing the viewport is not supported through the API or the Controls. These get handled by touch-controls on the Video element (or the device gyro).